# localtime_s fails where gmtime_s succeeds with dates before 1-1-1970

Tags: c++, c++-chrono, time-t

I'm trying to get the current year stored in a date from before 1970 using an `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>`, however I've run into an issue regarding the reading from its contents into a `std::tm` struct.

I convert the `time_point` to a `time_t` first, after which I read its values to get the `tm_year` value. However, when trying to do so, the code fails when using `localtime_s`, however it succeeds when I'm using `gmtime_s`. This is only for dates before 1-1-1970, dates after that work fine using both functions.

The code below reproduces the error. If `terstGmTimeVsLocalTime` is called with `utc=true` it works, if it is called with `utc=false` it doesn't produce the correct output.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

void testGmTimeVsLocaltime(const bool& utc) {
    // Create time
    std::tm timeInfoWrite = std::tm();
    timeInfoWrite.tm_year = 1969 - 1900;    // Year to parse, here it is 1969
    timeInfoWrite.tm_mon = 0;
    timeInfoWrite.tm_mday = 1;
    timeInfoWrite.tm_hour = 1;
    timeInfoWrite.tm_min = 0;
    timeInfoWrite.tm_sec = 0;
    timeInfoWrite.tm_isdst = -1;

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> timePoint = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(utc ? _mkgmtime(&timeInfoWrite) : std::mktime(&timeInfoWrite));

    // Convert to time_t
    std::time_t timeT = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(timePoint);

    // Read values
    std::tm timeInfoRead;
    if (utc) {
        gmtime_s(&timeInfoRead, &timeT);
    } else {
        localtime_s(&timeInfoRead, &timeT);
    }

    // Output result
    std::cout << (timeInfoRead.tm_year + 1900) << '\n';

    // Wait for input
    std::getchar();
}

int main() {
    testGmTimeVsLocaltime(true); // Set to false to show bug

    return 0;
}
```

`utc=true` outputs 1969, as would be expected. However, `utc=false` outputs 1899 (presumably since an error occurs and `tm_year` gets set to -1).

Is there anything I'm missing? [The documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime) doesn't specifically specify that `localtime_s` should fail for dates before 1-1-1970.

I'm on Windows 10 x64 if it makes a difference.

Comment: The MSDN docs suggest it will fail: "Before midnight, January 1, 1970." See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf12f0hc.aspx

Comment: @RichardCritten Ah, I see I must've been using an OS specific implementation. Didn't realize `localtime_s` wasn't part of the standard.

Would there be another function which would not fail for values before midnight, January 1, 1970? Or maybe another strategy?
I suppose I could retrieve the difference between UTC and localtime, simply use the `gmtime_s` function and then add the difference to the result when local time is required, however it seems like it could be done simpler.

Comment: The docs you link say _"Converts given time since __epoch__"_; where epoch is when the implementation decides time starts.  On Windows there are OS calls which will work for any time time, but I don't know of any standard API.

Comment: Your code fails with both `localtime_s` and `gmtime_s`. It's just failing differently. Try adding `std::cout << "timeT = " << timeT << '\n'`;`; you'll see that it's `-1` in both cases. (Also, you need `#include <chrono>`.) Change `1969 - 1900` to `1959 - 1900` and it will still output `1969`.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source date lib](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html), you can completely side-step the clumsy, error and bug-prone C api, and work directly with a modern `<chrono>`-based system:

```
#include "chrono_io.h"
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

void
testGmTimeVsLocaltime()
{
    using namespace date;
    // Create time
    auto timeInfoWrite = 1969_y/jan/1;
    sys_days timePoint = timeInfoWrite;  // this is a chrono::time_point
    std::cout << timePoint.time_since_epoch() << '\n'; // -365 days

    // Convert to time_t
    // no need

    // Read values
    year_month_day timeInfoRead = timePoint;

    // Output result
    std::cout << timeInfoRead.year() << '\n';
}

int
main()
{
    testGmTimeVsLocaltime();
}
```

Output:

```
-365[86400]s
1969
```

There are literals to make it easy to fill in a `year_month_day` struct which is the analog to the year, month and day parts of a `tm`.  You can easily convert this to a `std::chrono::time_point<system_clock, days>` (`sys_days`).  This is the same as a `system_clock::time_point`, but with a precision of days instead.  It itself will implicitly convert to a seconds-precision `time_point` (typedef'd to `sys_seconds`), or to a `system_clock::time_point`.

Above I just output its `time_since_epoch()` which shows that it is -365 days prior to the epoch.

There's never really any need to convert to C API data structures, but it is easy if you want to.  For example, assuming `time_t` is seconds since 1970-01-01:

```
std::time_t timeT = sys_seconds{timePoint}.time_since_epoch().count();
std::cout << timeT << '\n';
```

which outputs:

```
-31536000
```

The reverse conversion (back to `year_month_day`) is just as easy.  If you want to convert from `timeT` it is just slightly more involved:

```
year_month_day timeInfoRead = floor<days>(sys_seconds{seconds{timeT}});
```

This first converts `time_t` to `chrono::seconds`, and then to a `seconds`-precsion `time_point`, and then to a `days`-precsion `time_point`, finally to the `year_month_day` field type (`tm`-like).

Finally `year_month_day` has a `year()` getter member function which is streamable.  You can explicitly convert `year` to `int` if desired:

```
int{timeInfoRead.year()}
```

But I think it best to keep things like years, months and days as distinct types so that the compiler can help you catch when you accidentally mix them up.

Finally, if you really meant that you wanted 1969-01-01 00:00:00 in your computer's *local timezone*, [there's a library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) to do that as well.  And it is just a minor modification of the simple program above.

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>

void
testGmTimeVsLocaltime()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    // Create time
    auto timeInfoWrite = 1969_y/jan/1;
    auto timePoint = make_zoned(current_zone(), local_days{timeInfoWrite});

    // Convert to time_t
    std::time_t timeT = timePoint.get_sys_time().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::cout << timeT << '\n';

    // Read values
    timePoint = sys_seconds{seconds{timeT}};
    year_month_day timeInfoRead{floor<days>(timePoint.get_local_time())};

    // Output result
    std::cout << timeInfoRead.year() << '\n';
}

int
main()
{
    testGmTimeVsLocaltime();
}
```

Output:

```
-31518000
1969
```

Now you create a `zoned_seconds` using the computer's `current_zone()` timezone, and converting your `timeInfoWrite` to `local_days` instead of to `sys_days`.

You can get the local time or the system time out of `timePoint`.  For converting to `time_t`, system time makes the most sense:

```
std::time_t timeT = timePoint.get_sys_time().time_since_epoch().count();
```

And now the output (for me) is 5h later (18000s).

```
-31518000
```

You can get back either the local year, or the system (UTC) year, by either using `.get_local_time()` or `.get_sys_time()`.  For me it makes no difference (`"America/New_York"`).  But if you're in `"Australia/Sydney"`, you'll get 1968 if you request the UTC year instead of 1969.  And that's all very easy to simulate by simply substituting `"Australia/Sydney"` or `"America/New_York"` for `current_zone()` in the program above.

Yes, it works on Windows, VS-2013 and later.  There is some installation required for the timezone lib:  https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation